# Trying to get realpath to work traversing up a directory

Tags: php

I was under the impression the following generate the correct path (above document root):

> define('ROOT', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../'));

CURRENT Document `ROOT: /Users/SwindonWeb/Dropbox`
Trying to make it `/Users/SwindonWeb/`

I'm trying to find a script where the 1st part `($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` is always the same, but the second part `(../)` can be anything so that the ROOT can be set with a definitive path.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem using:

define('ROOT', dirname(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Any/Other/Path/Here/')));

dirname goes up one folder from the DOCUMENT ROOT and '/Any/Other/Path/Here/' added. If you require to go up two folders just delete 'Here' and if you want to go up three, delete 'Path/Here'.